# How do I change a static variable within a function?

Tags: php, function, static, scope

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I thought I would ask. For reasons that are long, management related, and boring... it would be very useful to be able to change a variable declared as `static` within a method inside a class. For example:

```
class Test{
    function staticFunction() {
        static $value = 'Hello, world!';
    }
}
```

For the sake of this problem, I can't change the code inside `Test::staticFunction()`. So, this is not a class variable accessible though `self::$value`, but a variable defined within the scope of this function only. Is there any way to change that `$value` variable from outside the method scope?

Comment: is this the property of the class as well ?

Comment: No, it's a static only defined within that method.

Comment: why not return it ? anyway try clone the object and see in var_dump if you can see the value

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: `var_dump` outputs only object members

Comment: think of a way to serialize this object state in to a file and then search the file for this value and grab it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static), it can't be done:

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

Funny things, those PHP static variables.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar( $param )
    {
        static $enigma = 'cogito ergo sum';
        $enigma = $param;
    }
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod( 'Foo', 'bar' );
var_dump( $method->getStaticVariables() );

$test = new Foo;
$test->bar( 'bar' );

$method = new ReflectionMethod( $test, 'bar' );
var_dump( $method->getStaticVariables() );
```

Comment: Apologies, I used the wrong word in my question, I need to be able to edit it.

Comment: Oh .. you want to **change** it.

Comment: Yeah. I worded the question poorly.

Comment: It could be possible to do this with [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureThis()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php), but it's not part of php 5.4 ... it might be smarted to extend the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The static variable defined when the function body executes first time.
in your example:

`static $value = 'Hello, world!';`

variable $value with value 'Hello, world!' will be defined when function will be called first time... other times when function will be called this line will be ignored until script will not stop execution. Static variable hold its data and will not be destroyed like local variables, when function body will be executed.